# I think Tomcat or Apache could be rearranging my HTML. Is that possible?

Tags: java, html, apache, tomcat

I'm using an old HTML trick to eliminate spaces between inline elements on my page, which involves placing the closing angle-bracket on the next line:

```
<button>One</button
><button>Two</button
><button>Three</button>
```

This has worked fine in our deployed web application for some time. But we just recently deployed to a new platform, and the HTML is rendering "properly" instead of the way I have it in the JSP:

```
<button>One</button>
<button>Two</button>
<button>Three</button>
```

**Exact** same source, so it's gotta be environment-related. Could it be Apache or Tomcat or OS?

The one that works:

- CentOS 6.7
- Apache 2.2.15

The one that doesn't work:

- CentOS 7
- Apache 2.4.6

Am I crazy? (Don't answer that part....)

Comment: Why not take the opportunity to fix this with the appropriate CSS? HTML is not and should not be used for presentation.

Comment: @Michael, I plan to, and that'll be my end solution, but I'd like to understand the behavior for educational reasons.

Comment: should be easy to check: Compare the results when connecting to port 80 and 8080 - one is Apache httpd, the other is tomcat. If it's Apache: Check the modules that are activated by default - maybe the name of one of them rings a bell